# Regex to find pattern matching two strings with 'x' number of spaces between them

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a situation where I am looking for specific words following one another, but I don't know how many spaces there are between those words, there are also parenthesis in there now that I think of it.

Here's an example:

```
word1 word2('word3')
```

The regex I'm looking for must find patterns where there can be any number of spaces:

- between word1 and word2
- between word2 and (
- between ( and '
- between ' and )

I just want word3, not 'word3'.

Anybody have any idea how the regex will look? I'm stumped.

I don't know what word3 is, but I do know what word1 and word2 is.

Just another example:

There can be multiple occurrences of this pattern in the string.

Say my text is as follow:

```
car   audi('q5') blah blah blah car    audi  ( 'a3') blah blah
more blah and even more car  audi( 'r8' ) blah end.
```

All I want from this is: q5, a3, r8

That's it. I don't know what these values will be or how many there are, all I know is 'car' and 'audi'.

Comment: Put spaces with quantifiers everywhere in the pattern and use a capture group to get "word3".

Comment: What regex are you currently using? Please include your attempt(s)

Comment: Probably no reason to even worry about what's in between the words. Just search for word borders with `\b`. For example: `\b\w+\b`

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Even with Edit 2, it still isn't clear of your requirements. I'm trying to make sense of it all, and, the way how it's worded is why you're ending up with very different answers. Consider rewriting your question to offer my clarity of your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
/word1\s*word2\s*\(\s*'word3'\s*\)/g
```

See this working [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3gd3i).

```js
let strings = [
  "word1 word2('word3')",
  "word1   word2('word3')",
  "word1 word2  ('word3')",
  "word1 word2(    'word3')",
  "word1 word2('word3'     )",
  "word1    word2    (   'word3'   )",
  "word1word2('word3')",
];

for (const str of strings) {
  console.log(`"${str}" -> ${/word1\s*word2\s*\(\s*'word3'\s*\)/g.test(str)}`);
}
```

Results:

```
"word1 word2('word3')" -> true
"word1   word2('word3')" -> true
"word1 word2  ('word3')" -> true
"word1 word2(    'word3')" -> true
"word1 word2('word3'     )" -> true
"word1    word2    (   'word3'   )" -> true
"word1word2('word3')" -> true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strr  = "word1 word2('word3')somethingDifferent";
console.log( strr.replace(/(\(|\)|')/g,' ').replace(/\s+/g , ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

We need two regexes:

1. First regex will be used to extract strings like: `car audi ('q5')`
2. Second regex will be used to clean up the matched strings to get: `q5`

```js
var str = [
  "car   audi('q5') blah blah blah car    audi  ( 'a3') blah blah",
  "more blah and even more car  audi( 'r8' ) blah end."
].join("\n") + "\n";

var m = str.match(/(car)\s*(audi)\s*\(\s*'(\w+)'\s*\)/g);

console.log("Intermediate results:");
console.log(m);

// m = [
//  "car   audi('q5')",
//  "car    audi  ( 'a3')",
//  "car  audi( 'r8' )"
// ]

m = m.map(function (e) {
  return e.match(/(car)\s*(audi)\s*\(\s*'(\w+)'\s*\)/)[3];
} );

console.log("Final results:");
console.log(m);

// m = [ 'q5', 'a3', 'r8' ]
```

Let's understand why this works.
The first regular expression I used looked like this:

```
/(car)\s*(audi)\s*\(\s*'(\w+)'\s*\)/g
```

Eventhough I used a capturing group, they will be ignored because I put a `/g` on the end. This will match all sentences matching your required pattern. It will find exactly those 3 car audi sentences.

Then, the second regular expression I used looks like this:

```
/(car)\s*(audi)\s*\(\s*'(\w+)'\s*\)/
```

i.e. I removed the `/g`. Now the capture groups for each word will match `car` `audi` and `q5` respectively. You indicated you're interested in the 3rd word, which is why I put [3] on the end to grab only the 3rd word and discard everything else from the match.

Here's an explanation of key components in the regular expression:

- `\w+` will match words containing 1 or more letters or numbers
- `\s*` will match 0, 1 or more spaces.
- `(\w+)` will not only match the word but put it in a capturing group (i.e. give me a copy)

Here's a reduced version of the solution:

```js
var str = [
    "car   audi('q5') blah blah blah car    audi  ( 'a3') blah blah",
    "more blah and even more car  audi( 'r8' ) blah end."
].join("\n") + "\n";

var m = (str.match(/(car)\s*(audi)\s*\(\s*'(\w+)'\s*\)/g) || []).map(function (e) {
  return e.match(/(car)\s*(audi)\s*\(\s*'(\w+)'\s*\)/)[3];
} );

console.log(m); // ["q5","a3","r8"]
```

Also note that in this final version, I added `|| []`. This is to handle the condition where there's no matching sentences to ensure we return a clean empty array instead of causing an error due to a null intermediate result.